# How can I edit the source of a gradle library and use the changes in my project?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-library

Let's use [Yalantis Phoenix Library](https://github.com/Yalantis/Phoenix) as an example. I don't want to import the project via gradle, but I want to edit and use the source code of the library since the author provides no way to edit some of the files programatically.

The way I've done, it is the following:

1. Unzip folder
2. File > New > Import Module (select Phoenix-master folder)
3. Now, my gradle file has:

   ```
   dependencies {  
       //...  
       compile project(':library')  
   }
   ```

But the library doesn't compile. What step am I missing?

I get the following error:

```
Error:Could not find method isReleaseBuild() for arguments [] on project ':library' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

Comment: add this `compile 'com.yalantis:phoenix:1.2.3'` under dependency

Comment: https://github.com/Yalantis/Phoenix#usage

Comment: The problem is if I build via gradle I can't edit some of the components that I want to edit. I want to import the full library and source code.

Comment: then you have to copy paste the required files/resources in your project (use different package ) and edit the code

Comment: So if I wanted to replace ``Phoenix-master\library\src\main\res\drawable-xxxhdpi\buildings.png`` with another image how would I do this?

Comment: Why don't you simply replace this image in the folder ? If you want to change the name as well, just do a Regex search for the existing name and replace with the new name all over the app code and rebuild. Is there any issue with this ?

Comment: I guess I'm just a newbie. Do I just copy and paste the entire library folder into my app? It doesn't seem like I can edit folder contents just by including the grade dependency.

Answer (score 2):

Change these lines:

```
dependencies {
//...
    compile project(':library')
}
```

into

```
dependencies {
//...
 compile 'com.yalantis:phoenix:1.2.3'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please read the usage guidelines already given in the link here [Usage](https://github.com/Yalantis/Phoenix#usage)
. Include the library as local library project.

```
compile 'com.yalantis:phoenix:1.2.3'
```