# Swap out .jar library for its source, using Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, jar

For a university project, I need to perform profiling for a big project I am normally not affiliated with. I can download the project, import it into IntelliJ and edit the source code. However, I also need to instrument the code for some of its dependencies. They come in `.jar` files, along with their source code, so I can browse it, but it is read-only. How can I change that?

What I have done so far: the library in question is listed both under Libraries tab, and Modules > "my module" > dependencies. I can choose `copy as a module library` [I am not sure what this is meant to actually do] and save the files to a particular location. Inside the `.jar` I get this way, reside both `.class` and `.java` files, so I can unzip it and grab the source files. But still, I need to somehow remove the dependency on `.jar` and tell `gradle` to instead compile and use the contents of this new directory.

The project in question is [here](https://github.com/brmson/yodaqa) and the dependency I want to edit is pulled in [here](https://github.com/brmson/yodaqa/blob/master/build.gradle#L126). I don't have to use IntelliJ, it's just what I have experimented with so far.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41315999/how-can-i-edit-the-source-of-a-gradle-library-and-use-the-changes-in-my-project) solution doesn't work - as you can see above, the import already comes in the `compile 'x'` form, and still it's read-only. Other answers I found were just cases when a simple subclass would do, which is not the case for me.

Comment: JAR files ideally shouldn't contain `.java` files. The "read only" code you have is IntelliJ decompiling the `.class` files.

Comment: See if this helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38877989/intellij-gradle-add-module-dependency/38878290#38878290